# React Redux Component Lifecycle Link async functions

Tags: reactjs, redux, mern

My issue is that I have 2 components. They are not sibling components. When I click the first component, it is a link to the parent of the second component. This link has an onClick function that takes the id of the component clicked and finds the object in the database with a matching id and makes it accessible in props as its own object. In the child of the component that you go to after you click this link, I was trying to use ComponentDidMount() with a function that gets a new set of objects from the backend based on the id of the returned object in props from the first function performed. It currently returns undefined, because the first function is happening too slowly I think. Any suggestions?

Comment: can you please provide some code? We can't really be very useful otherwise.

Comment: The suggestion is to update the question with https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve instead of describing the code. Otherwise it's considered off-topic and can be closed.

Comment: Alright thanks for info guys, here is what I currently have